# Samsung Galaxy-s blocks the app to install after download

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, installation

Why I can not install the app after download on galaxy s, if the app is not from the play store it blocks the app to install.  I know there is an option on new models of galaxy, if it blocks your app to download there is option to go to settings and then you click on allow app from unknown source.  But on galaxy s I can not find that option. Please help me to download and install this Hailo Taxi App, out of play store.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in Settings..

**Settings** -> **Security** -> **Device administration** -> **Unknown sources**